# How to properly save a plot as an eps file in GNU/Octave?

Tags: plot, octave

I'm trying to save an image with the eps format on GNU/Octave, but something is wrong. Here's a screenshot of what it should look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3339.png]

and here is what i get:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bDys.jpg]

I have no idea what is happening in here, can someone enlighten me?
I plotted the figure using the contourf command, and printed it with:

```
print(figure(2),'-deps','-color','test.eps')
```

Viewed the image on GIMP, evince and trying to use it on a LaTeX document. Same problem happened on all of them.

Using: Octave 3.8.1 on xubuntu 64bits

Comment: What did you use to view the eps file (or to convert it into a JPEG)? Also, could you post which version of  octave you're using (type `version`)?

Comment: Used GIMP, and i'm trying to insert the images on LATEX, also the same problem happened there.
I'm using octave version 3.8.1 in Xubuntu 64bits

Comment: I think this could be a problem with gl2ps. Which GPU do you use? Do you see the white stripes in the background with "demo ("area", 1); print -debug -depsc out.eps". A workaround is to switch to gnuplot : "graphics_toolkit gnuplot" before any plotting (directly after startup)

Comment: Thanks, the workaround helped me. But for some reason, that only happened with the contourf f command. I'm plotting everything with imagesc now anyway, but i will remember to use only gnuplot for now on.